# How can I combine tkinter GUI and pyglet graphics?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyglet

I am trying to combine tkinter and pyglet into one application. Using tkinter for the gui, one component of which is a canvas and I would like to use pyglet to paint/draw on that canvas. Is this possible? Examples I found show two separate windows. That's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes, theoretically this is possible. But double-check if this is really necessary, cause such a mix of GUI libraries is difficult to control, since they both have separate event loops, so they must be synchronized somehow. I don’t think it is worth it, especially because synchronization is not the only problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The reason I would like to do this is because tkinter does not antialias, so 2D graphics look really bad (think plots, charts, etc.)